# Delphi XE7 - TDBChart not displaying series

Tags: delphi, linechart, delphi-xe7

We have the following code in our application to show a percentage value over time for multiple branches of a company. The branch names are displayed in a custom checkbox panel which you can add check boxes to dynamically to show or not show a particular branch. There is a procedure on a button click to Open the queries and should then display the series on the chart. However, it does not display the series. The queries return data and the axis on the chart do change to accommodate the range of values returned by the query. This was originally developed in Delphi 10, this is now not working in Delphi XE7.

```
type
  TBranchItem = class
    procedure CheckBoxClick(Sender: TObject);
  private
    FColour: TColor;
  public
    BranchID: integer;
    Query: TADOQuery;
    CheckBox: TCheckBox;
    property Colour: TColor read FColour write FColour;

    constructor Create(const Connection: TADOConnection);
    destructor Destroy;

  end;

  TfrmGiftAidBranchSummary = class(TfrmBaseMts)
    Panel1: TPanel;
    mtsBackButton1: TmtsBackButton;
    chGAProportion: TDBChart;
    Q: TADOQuery;
    cbpBranches: TCheckBoxPanel;
    Panel2: TPanel;
    edStartMonth: TEdit;
    Label1: TLabel;
    Label2: TLabel;
    edEndMonth: TEdit;
    lblStartDate: TLabel;
    lblEndDate: TLabel;
    btnDraw: TmtsButton;
    chkIncluderefunds: TCheckBox;
    procedure FormShow(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure mtsBackButton1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure btnDrawClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure edStartMonthChange(Sender: TObject);
    procedure edEndMonthChange(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
    FColourArray: array[0..99] of TColor;
    FBranchItemArray: array of TBranchItem;

    procedure FillColourArray;
    procedure DrawGAProportionChart;
    procedure CreateBranchItems;
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;


var
  frmGiftAidBranchSummary: TfrmGiftAidBranchSummary;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

{ TfrmGiftAidBranchSummary }

procedure TfrmGiftAidBranchSummary.btnDrawClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  inherited;
  Screen.Cursor := crHourGlass;
  DrawGAProportionChart;
  Screen.Cursor := crDefault;
end;

procedure TfrmGiftAidBranchSummary.CreateBranchItems;
var
  Count: integer;
  LineSeriesArray: array of TChartSeries;
begin
  Q.Close;
  Q.SQL.Clear;
  Q.SQL.Add('SELECT BranchID, Name FROM BranchTransfer');
  Q.SQL.Add('WHERE Webshop = 0 AND BranchController = 0');
  Q.SQL.Add('AND BranchID > 0');
  Q.SQL.Add('ORDER BY BranchID');
  Q.Open;

  Count := 0;

  SetLength(FBranchItemArray, Q.RecordCount);
  SetLength(LineSeriesArray, Q.RecordCount);

  while not Q.Eof do
  begin
    FBranchItemArray[Count] := TBranchItem.Create(dmMainDataModule.dbMTS);
    FBranchItemArray[Count].BranchID := Q.FieldByName('BranchID').AsInteger;
    FBranchItemArray[Count].Colour := FColourArray[Count];
    FBranchItemArray[Count].CheckBox := cbpBranches.AddCheckBox(Q.FieldByName('Name').AsString, True, FBranchItemArray[Count].Colour);
    FBranchItemArray[Count].CheckBox.OnClick := FBranchItemArray[Count].CheckBoxClick;

    FBranchItemArray[Count].Query.Close;
    FBranchItemArray[Count].Query.SQL.Clear;
    FBranchItemArray[Count].Query.SQL.Add('SELECT A.BranchID, DonatedValue, GiftAidValue, A.month_no,');
    FBranchItemArray[Count].Query.SQL.Add('CASE WHEN DonatedValue = 0 THEN 0 ELSE (GiftAidValue/DonatedValue) * 100 END AS GAProportion');
    FBranchItemArray[Count].Query.SQL.Add('FROM');
    FBranchItemArray[Count].Query.SQL.Add('(SELECT branchid, SUM(value) AS DonatedValue, month_no from audit');
    FBranchItemArray[Count].Query.SQL.Add('WHERE trans_type in (''CS'', ''CRS'', ''VS'')');
    FBranchItemArray[Count].Query.SQL.Add('AND stock_type = ''G''');
    FBranchItemArray[Count].Query.SQL.Add('AND BranchID = ' + IntToStr(FBranchItemArray[Count].BranchID));
    FBranchItemArray[Count].Query.SQL.Add('AND Month_no >= ' + edStartMonth.Text);
    FBranchItemArray[Count].Query.SQL.Add('AND Month_no <= ' + edEndMonth.Text);
    FBranchItemArray[Count].Query.SQL.Add('AND Qty > 0');
    FBranchItemArray[Count].Query.SQL.Add('GROUP BY BranchID, month_no) A');
    FBranchItemArray[Count].Query.SQL.Add('LEFT Join');
    FBranchItemArray[Count].Query.SQL.Add('(SELECT branchid, SUM(value) AS GiftAidValue, month_no from audit');
    FBranchItemArray[Count].Query.SQL.Add('WHERE trans_type in (''CS'', ''CRS'', ''VS'')');
    FBranchItemArray[Count].Query.SQL.Add('AND stock_type = ''G''');
    FBranchItemArray[Count].Query.SQL.Add('AND Month_no >= ' + edStartMonth.Text);
    FBranchItemArray[Count].Query.SQL.Add('AND Month_no <= ' + edEndMonth.Text);
    FBranchItemArray[Count].Query.SQL.Add('AND Qty > 0');
    FBranchItemArray[Count].Query.SQL.Add('AND DonorAccountID IN (SELECT Account_id FROM customer WHERE GiftAid <> 0)');
    FBranchItemArray[Count].Query.SQL.Add('AND BranchID = ' + IntToStr(FBranchItemArray[Count].BranchID));
    FBranchItemArray[Count].Query.SQL.Add('GROUP BY BranchID, month_no) G');
    FBranchItemArray[Count].Query.SQL.Add('ON A.BranchID = G.BranchID');
    FBranchItemArray[Count].Query.SQL.Add('and A.month_no = G.month_no');
    FBranchItemArray[Count].Query.SQL.Add('ORDER BY month_no, BranchID');

    LineSeriesArray[Count] := TChartSeries.Create(chGAProportion);
    LineSeriesArray[Count].ParentChart := chGAProportion;
    LineSeriesArray[Count].DataSource := FBranchItemArray[Count].Query;
    LineSeriesArray[Count].CheckDatasource;
    LineSeriesArray[Count].YValues.ValueSource := 'GAProportion';
    LineSeriesArray[Count].XValues.ValueSource := 'Month_no';
    LineSeriesArray[Count].XLabelsSource := 'Month_no';
    LineSeriesArray[Count].SeriesColor := FColourArray[Count];
    LineSeriesArray[Count].Pen.Width := 2;

    SetChecked(FBranchItemArray[Count].CheckBox, True);

    Inc(Count);
    Q.Next;
  end;

  chGAProportion.AddSeries(LineSeriesArray);
end;

procedure TfrmGiftAidBranchSummary.DrawGAProportionChart;
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  for i := 0 to Length(FBranchItemArray) - 1 do
  begin
    FBranchItemArray[i].Query.Close;

    FBranchItemArray[i].Query.SQL[7] := 'AND Month_no >= ' + edStartMonth.Text;
    FBranchItemArray[i].Query.SQL[8] := 'AND Month_no <= ' + edEndMonth.Text;
    FBranchItemArray[i].Query.SQL[15] := 'AND Month_no >= ' + edStartMonth.Text;
    FBranchItemArray[i].Query.SQL[16] := 'AND Month_no <= ' + edEndMonth.Text;


    if chkIncluderefunds.Checked then
    begin
      FBranchItemArray[i].Query.SQL[9] := '';
      FBranchItemArray[i].Query.SQL[17] := '';
    end
    else
    begin
      FBranchItemArray[i].Query.SQL[9] := 'AND Qty > 0';
      FBranchItemArray[i].Query.SQL[17] := 'AND Qty > 0';
    end;

    if FBranchItemArray[i].CheckBox.Checked then
      FBranchItemArray[i].Query.Open;
  end;

end;

procedure TfrmGiftAidBranchSummary.edEndMonthChange(Sender: TObject);
begin
  inherited;
  Q.Close;
  Q.SQL.Clear;
  Q.SQL.Add('SELECT MAX(trans_date) AS trans_date FROM audit WHERE Month_no = ' + edEndMonth.Text);
  Q.Open;

  if not (Q.Bof and Q.Eof) then
    lblEndDate.Caption := FormatDateTime('dd/mm/yy', Q.FieldByName('trans_date').AsDateTime)
  else
    lblEndDate.Caption := 'Not Found';
end;

procedure TfrmGiftAidBranchSummary.edStartMonthChange(Sender: TObject);
begin
  inherited;
  Q.Close;
  Q.SQL.Clear;
  Q.SQL.Add('SELECT MIN(trans_date) AS trans_date FROM audit WHERE Month_no = ' + edStartMonth.Text);
  Q.Open;

  if not (Q.Bof and Q.Eof) then
    lblStartDate.Caption := FormatDateTime('dd/mm/yy', Q.FieldByName('trans_date').AsDateTime)
  else
    lblStartDate.Caption := 'Not Found';
end;

{ TBranchItem }

procedure TBranchItem.CheckBoxClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if Checkbox.Checked then
    Query.Open
  else
    Query.Close;
end;

constructor TBranchItem.Create(const Connection: TADOConnection);
begin
  Query := TADOQuery.Create(nil);
  Query.Connection := Connection;
end;

destructor TBranchItem.Destroy;
begin
  Query.Free;
end;

procedure TfrmGiftAidBranchSummary.FillColourArray;
begin
  FColourArray[0] := $008080;
  FColourArray[1] := $FFB6C1;
  FColourArray[2] := $00FFFF;
  FColourArray[3] := $7FFFD4;
  FColourArray[4] := $000000;
  FColourArray[5] := $FFEBCD;
  FColourArray[6] := $0000FF;
  FColourArray[7] := $8A2BE2;
  FColourArray[8] := $A52A2A;
  FColourArray[9] := $DEB887;
  FColourArray[10] := $5F9EA0;
  FColourArray[11] := $7FFF00;
  FColourArray[12] := $D2691E;
  FColourArray[13] := $6495ED;
  FColourArray[14] := $DC143C;
  FColourArray[15] := $00008B;
  FColourArray[16] := $008B8B;
  FColourArray[17] := $B8860B;
  FColourArray[18] := $A9A9A9;
  FColourArray[19] := $006400;
  FColourArray[20] := $BDB76B;
  FColourArray[21] := $8B008B;
  FColourArray[22] := $556B2F;
  FColourArray[23] := $FF8C00;
  FColourArray[24] := $9932CC;
  FColourArray[25] := $8B0000;
  FColourArray[26] := $E9967A;
  FColourArray[27] := $8FBC8F;
  FColourArray[28] := $483D8B;
  FColourArray[29] := $2F4F4F;
  FColourArray[30] := $00CED1;
  FColourArray[31] := $9400D3;
  FColourArray[32] := $FF1493;
  FColourArray[33] := $00BFFF;
  FColourArray[34] := $696969;
  FColourArray[35] := $1E90FF;
  FColourArray[36] := $B22222;
  FColourArray[37] := $228B22;
  FColourArray[38] := $FF00FF;
  FColourArray[39] := $FFD700;
  FColourArray[40] := $DAA520;
  FColourArray[41] := $808080;
  FColourArray[42] := $008000;
  FColourArray[43] := $FF69B4;
  FColourArray[44] := $CD5C5C;
  FColourArray[45] := $4B0082;
  FColourArray[46] := $7CFC00;
  FColourArray[47] := $ADD8E6;
  FColourArray[48] := $F08080;
  FColourArray[49] := $90EE90;
  FColourArray[50] := $D3D3D3;
  FColourArray[51] := $FFA07A;
  FColourArray[52] := $20B2AA;
  FColourArray[53] := $87CEFA;
  FColourArray[54] := $778899;
  FColourArray[55] := $B0C4DE;
  FColourArray[56] := $00FF00;
  FColourArray[57] := $32CD32;
  FColourArray[58] := $800000;
  FColourArray[59] := $66CDAA;
  FColourArray[60] := $0000CD;
  FColourArray[61] := $BA55D3;
  FColourArray[62] := $9370DB;
  FColourArray[63] := $3CB371;
  FColourArray[64] := $7B68EE;
  FColourArray[65] := $00FA9A;
  FColourArray[66] := $48D1CC;
  FColourArray[67] := $C71585;
  FColourArray[68] := $191970;
  FColourArray[69] := $000080;
  FColourArray[70] := $808000;
  FColourArray[71] := $6B8E23;
  FColourArray[72] := $FFA500;
  FColourArray[73] := $FF4500;
  FColourArray[74] := $DA70D6;
  FColourArray[75] := $98FB98;
  FColourArray[76] := $AFEEEE;
  FColourArray[77] := $DB7093;
  FColourArray[78] := $FFDAB9;
  FColourArray[79] := $CD853F;
  FColourArray[80] := $FFC0CB;
  FColourArray[81] := $DDA0DD;
  FColourArray[82] := $B0E0E6;
  FColourArray[83] := $800080;
  FColourArray[84] := $FF0000;
  FColourArray[85] := $BC8F8F;
  FColourArray[86] := $4169E1;
  FColourArray[87] := $8B4513;
  FColourArray[88] := $FA8072;
  FColourArray[89] := $F4A460;
  FColourArray[90] := $2E8B57;
  FColourArray[91] := $A0522D;
  FColourArray[92] := $C0C0C0;
  FColourArray[93] := $87CEEB;
  FColourArray[94] := $6A5ACD;
  FColourArray[95] := $708090;
  FColourArray[96] := $00FF7F;
  FColourArray[97] := $4682B4;
  FColourArray[98] := $D2B48C;
  FColourArray[99] := $008080;
end;

procedure TfrmGiftAidBranchSummary.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  inherited;
  FillColourArray;
end;

procedure TfrmGiftAidBranchSummary.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
  inherited;
  with TADOQuery.Create(nil) do
  try
    Connection := dmMainDataModule.dbMTS;

    Close;
    SQL.Clear;
    SQL.Add('SELECT month_no FROM Sequence');
    Open;

    edStartMonth.Text := '1';

    if not (Q.Bof and Q.Eof) then
      edEndMonth.Text := FieldByName('month_no').AsString
    else
      edEndMonth.Text := '1';
  finally
    Free;
  end;

  CreateBranchItems;
end;

procedure TfrmGiftAidBranchSummary.mtsBackButton1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  inherited;
  ModalResult := mrOK;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Instead of
`LineSeriesArray[Count] := TChartSeries.Create(chGAProportion);`
it should have been
`LineSeriesArray[Count] := TLineSeries.Create(chGAProportion);`
Changed this and now working fine.